# Django Raises ImproperlyConfigured When Trying to Create A Menu by django-admin-tools

Tags: python, django

I successfully configured django-admin-tools for using. I tried to create a custom menu [as told in documentation](http://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customization.html#customizing-the-navigation-menu) as below:

```
python3 manage.py custommenu
```

However, this raised an `ImproperlyConfugured` error below, saying:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: app_dirs must not be set when loaders is defined.
```

I looked at the directory, menu.py is successfully created, yet the content is empty in opposition to the documentation.

My confituration of `TEMPLATES` variable is below:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader',
            ],
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                'admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Does that mean I need to install `django-admin-tools` before creating any app?

## Enviroment

- python3
- django 1.8.7

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Remove the `'APP_DIRS': True,` line.

Comment: I have templates inside my applications, will this affect that?

Comment: It seems installing django-admin-tools crashed my other apps, I'll give this a try.

Comment: @Eray, nope, removing that line shouldn't affect your templates, as long as you have the `loaders` section filled with the templates loaders (and you seem to have it).

Comment: Strangely, my other app raises `TypeError: 'Loader' object is not iterable` on page when returning. It seems I will remove django-admin-tools. But I'll accept this as valid answer since it solved my particular problem. Thanks. ^^

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to know why you'd need to remove `'APP_DIRS': True,` to make it work then I would suggest you have a read in the docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader
Note: Please use the corresponding docs for your django version.

**In general:**
`APP_DIRS` and the option `loaders` does not work together, so you're left with two options:

1. remove `loaders` from `OPTIONS`
2. remove `APP_DIRS`

**Re question:**
Since Erdin wanted to use `'admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader'` he had to remove `APP_DIRS`. However, you might tumble across this question for a different reason and so considering option number 1 might be worthwhile.

Comment: If `loaders` is set, the cached template is used even if `DEBUG = True`

Answer (score 1):

Erdin Eray, I know it has been a while  but I ran into the `TypeError: 'Loader' object is not iterable` which is the problem you described in the comments of the accepted answer. This happened because I included `admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader` in the `context_processors`, as above, which causes the error. It should only be included in the `loaders`.